# What is the purpose of comparing two objects? (as opposed to primitives)

Tags: javascript, object, compare

I'm currently learning Javascript (I'm familiar with C# and Python), and currently the tutorial I'm reading is discussing comparison between two objects. In the coding I've done (I've had various projects), this sort of thing has never really been needed. Given that this might be important for the future, I thought I'd look for when/where to use object comparison, but all I can find are questions/answers on *how* it works, not *why* you should use it and when. I can't think of any situations off the top of my head where comparisons between primitives wouldn't be better, so any help in this area would be appreciated.

Comment: e.g. You can avoid extra calculations/calls if user just click on a button twice/thrice without changing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use it when you have two variables which refer to objects, and you want to see whether they refer to the same object. For example, with the `window` object, you can do

```js
if (window !== window.top) {
  console.log('This script must be running in an iframe!');
}
```

> I can't think of any situations off the top of my head where comparisons between primitives wouldn't be better

Many objects (including `window`) can't just be converted to a unique primitive easily.

You may be able to use `JSON.stringify` to convert a plain object to a string, and then compare those strings, but this won't help you compare whether the objects are *actually the same object in memory*:

```js
const obj1 = { prop: 'val' };
const obj2 = { prop: 'val' };
// They are not the same object
console.log(obj1 === obj2);
// But if you convert them to a primitive string first, you won't be able to tell
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2));
```

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of a circular argument, you use it when you need to use it. :-)

I'd say it's roughly the same as in C#. In both cases, when you use an equality operator, it tests to see whether they're the same object (rather than separate but equivalent objects).

For instance, suppose you have an array of objects, and the contents of that array can change. Later, you have an object you should remove. You'd compare the object to remove with the objects in the array to see if you should remove it (often in a `filter` operation):

```
arrayOfObjects = arrayOfObjects.filter(obj => obj !== objToRemove);
```

Comment: *(Sigh. If you see `===` in the above, hit refresh.)*